# Circular dependency created by serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When importing a serializer into my model the model cannot be imported anymore so I suspect there is a circular dependency.

When not importing the serializer everything goes smoothly but when importing it everything breaks.

This works

```py
from shift.models import Shift

class ShiftChangeRequest(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And this does not:

```py
from shift.models import Shift
from shift.serializers.base import BaseSerializer

class ShiftChangeRequest(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey(Shift, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

As you can see the ShiftChangeRequest does have a connection with shift but in the BaseSerializer ShiftChangeRequest is not even mentioned:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from shift import models


class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Shift
        fields = [
            "id",
            "title",
            "start",
            "end",
            "amount_of_minutes",
            "amount_of_employees",
            "client",
            "skills",
            "users",
            "repeat_at",
        ]
```

I expected that everything worked as before the import but I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'ShiftChangeRequest'`

`ShiftChangeRequest` gets imported in the `ShiftChangeRequestSerializer` which looks like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from shift_change.models import ShiftChangeRequest


class ShiftChangeRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShiftChangeRequest
        fields = ["id", "user", "switch_user", "shift", "message", "type", "accepted"]
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"allow_null": True, "required": False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if "user" not in validated_data:
            validated_data["user"] = self.context["request"].user

        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to import `from shift.serializers.base import BaseSerializer` locally in your `ShiftChangeRequest` class?

Comment: Yes that is what i am doing in the example where it does not work. I don't know if that answers your question?

Comment: The question is : why do you need to import base serializer in your models module ? keep models in one module and serializer in another one. keep things simple ?

Comment: I agree I didn't specify what I am exactly doing. I am implementing the microkernel or modular monolith architecture where the api should define a serializer and a model so modules can talk with eachother without knowing what they contain. So when I am importing the api I import the model and the serializer which than gives me this problem. I changed the context a bit to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `Shift`, you can use it like below.

```
from shift.serializers.base import BaseSerializer

class ShiftChangeRequest(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey('shift.Shift', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Inside serializer file import `Shift` class in meta class

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        from shift.models import Shift
        model = Shift
        fields = []
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this is does not work. I get the same error

Comment: Where you are trying to import `ShiftChangeRequest`?

Comment: In the serializer of shift change request. That is why I am fairly certain it is a circular dependency problem

Comment: If not please include shift chnage request serializer code too

Comment: It strangely did not work. I updated my answer with the serializer

Comment: Are you importing anything in `shift.models` from others files? from given structure I can't find any circular dependency.

Comment: No I am not. This is why I don't understand the error. I also used https://github.com/bndr/pycycle and it told me I did not have any circular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In **models.py** remove this line:

```
from shift.serializers.base import BaseSerializer
```

No need import Serializer Class into models.py file

Comment: As mentioned in the comments: I am implementing the microkernel or modular monolith architecture where the api should define a serializer and a model so modules can talk with eachother without knowing what they contain. So when I am importing the api I import the model and the serializer which than gives me this problem. I changed the context a bit to make it easier to understand